# What happened to the Dataflow LinkTo parameter discardMessages?

Tags: .net, task-parallel-library, dataflow

In "Introduction to TPL Dataflow" Stephen Toub writes under LinkTo:
"... and what the behavior should be if the predicate is not met (e.g. should such a message simply be dropped, should such a message be declined and offered to other targets, etc.)"

In some examples I see a boolean being passed to the LinkTo method after the filter predicate and a parameter discardMessages is mentioned. For instance the links in this nice example [Tpl Dataflow walkthrough](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/bnaya/archive/2012/01/28/tpl-dataflow-walkthrough-part-5.aspx) do not compile:

```
linkBroadcaster.LinkTo(downloader, linkFilter, true);
```

I cannot find that parameter in the LinkTo overloads. Has this behavior changed to some default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The discardMessages parameter has been replaced by

```
...LinkTo(DataflowBlock.NullTarget)
```

For a more detailed discussion see [Dataflow MSDN forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tpldataflow/thread/d27ad0e0-ee86-4104-85cf-22eda1e11ee8)